# searching over multiple lines in the google appengine logs

Tags: regex, google-app-engine, logging

I wanted to use a regular expression that covers multiple lines to search in the google appengine log console. I've tried:

```
 firstpart.*\n(.*\n)+.*secondpart
 firstpart.*$(.*$)+.*secondpart
```

but neither of these work. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks, Richard

Comment: By multiple lines, do you mean multiple debug log entries, or multiple requests? I don't think either is possible.

Comment: @Nick - a single request but multiple debug entries. It seems to work except when the regex starts in the heading line that describes the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\n will work when searching inside the logs but not between the top line of the log of the form

```
 2011-06-23 10:07:24.522 /users/action?key=agl5cmVjZWlwdHNyEgsmljZRjR5YQDDA 302 ....
```

and the rest of the logs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly, but to search for line breaks you should use \r\n as opposed to just \n.

Comment: thanks for your answer \r\n works on windows machines \n on unix. Appengine uses the \n as a line break.